# Show only one partial view among many in ajax success method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my controler action method......from that action i want to return a partial view which is conditionaly true....and show this partial view in ajax success method....

```
      public ActionResul   InsertPestType    (PestTypeViewModel     model)
       {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
        {
            pest_type emp = new pest_type();
            ViewBag.emp = db.pest_type.SingleOrDefault(x => x.pest_type_name 
             == model.pest_type_name && x.isdeleted == false);
            if (ViewBag.emp != null)
            {
                emp = ViewBag.emp;
            }
            if (emp.pest_type_name == model.pest_type_name)
            { 
                ViewBag.Message = "This Pest Type is already exist in the 
                record";
                return PartialView("Insert_PestType", model);
            }
            else
            {
                emp.pest_type_name = model.pest_type_name;
                emp.isdeleted = false;
                db.pest_type.Add(emp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                List<pest_type> model1 = db.pest_type.Where(x => x.isdeleted 
                == false).ToList();
                ViewBag.pesttypelist = model1;
                return PartialView("pest_type_partial", model);
        }
        }
        else
            return PartialView("inex_partial", model);
    }
```

Below is my ajax success method.......here i want to show only one partial view which is true ocording to the condition...........Now my question is that how can i differentiate between two partial views in ajax success method??

var success=function(response)
    {

```
    if ()
    {          
        $("#RegisterPestTypeModel").modal('hide')
        $("#dvCategoryResults").html(response.AjaxReturn)

    }
    else
    {
        $("#PestTypeModalBody").html(response)
    }
```